# Difference between Topic DefaultMessageTimeToLive and Subscription DefaultMessageTimeToLive on Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

Both a **Topic** on the Azure Service Bus and an associated **Subscription** expose the `DefaultMessageTimeToLive` property; initialised like so:

```
if (!NamespaceManager.TopicExists(TopicName))
{
    NamespaceManager.CreateTopic(
        new TopicDescription(TopicName)
            {
                MaxSizeInMegabytes = 5120,
                DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(14)
            });
}

if (!NamespaceManager.SubscriptionExists(TopicName, SubscriptionName))
{
    NamespaceManager.CreateSubscription(
        new SubscriptionDescription(TopicName, SubscriptionName)
            {
                LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(7),
                EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = true
            });
}
```

What is the difference between the two and what is the purpose of having two TTL settings?  Furthermore; if a message expires on the **Topic** what happens to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TTL set on a Topic is applied to all of its subscriptions. subscriptions can have their own TT if needed, however it should be less than Topic TTL. TTL applied on subscription is applied on all the a messages sent to it and messages can have its own TTL which should be again less than Subscription TTL.
If the message expires and if DeadLettering enabled on the Subscription, expired messaged will be moved to DeadLetter queue else will be deleted permanently.

More info from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh780749.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reply Dhana; however I know that on a Topic you cannot set `EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration`, this can only be set on a Subscription.  This begs the question; why does Topic have a TTL at all

Comment: By reading through this document  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh780749.aspx) what I infer is its a convenience option to set TTL on Topic as you dont have to set it on each subscription and the expired messages seem to go to subscription's dead letter. Have not tried it though

Comment: _"Subscriptions inherit the TTL from the topic unless they are created explicitly with a smaller TTL. Based on whether dead-lettering is enabled, a message whose TTL has expired will either be moved to the subscription’s associated DeadLetterQueue or will be permanently deleted."_ -- Perfect thank you; @Dhana if you adjust your answer to match that I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: there you go, Answer is updated so someone else can benefit as well